# How to use environment values for group-id in spring KafkaListener annotation

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

I get the values from the .env file and try to put the value Group-id in @KafkaListener:

```
Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.load();
final String KAFKA_GROUP_ID = dotenv.get("SOME_KAFKA_GROUPID");

@KafkaListener(topics = "some_topic", groupId = KAFKA_GROUP_ID, containerFactory = "some_container_name")
```

IDEA says KAFKA_GROUP_ID must be constant. I have tried all modifications for KAFKA_GROUP_ID but have been unsuccessful.

How shall I proceed to get KAFKA_GROUP_ID constant?

Comment: Use `${SOME_KAFKA_GROUPID}` in your `groupId` attribute.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. I suppose it is applicable if I get the values from application.properties file.

Comment: is this spring or spring boot application @IgorPiven?

Comment: Then make `Dotenv` part of the propertysources, using an `EnvironmentPostProcessor`, and wrap the result in a `PropertySource`. Then it will work as the property is part of the normal flow.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring boot you can read system environment properties or spring environment properties using [@Value](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/spring-value-annotation#spring-value-spring-environment-property) annotation

**Spring @Value - Spring Environment Property**

```
@Value("${APP_NAME_NOT_FOUND}")
private String defaultAppName;
```

If the key is not found in the spring environment properties, then the property value will be `${APP_NAME_NOT_FOUND}`. We can assign a default value that will get assigned if the key is missing from spring environment properties.

```
@Value("${APP_NAME_NOT_FOUND:Default}")
private String defaultAppName;
```

**Spring @Value - System Environment**

When Spring environment is populated, it reads all the system environment variables and stores it as properties. So we can assign system variables too using @Value annotation.

```
@Value("${java.home}")
private String javaHome;

@Value("${HOME}")
private String homeDir;
```

**Spring @Value - SpEL**

We can also use Spring Expression Language with @Value annotation. So we can read java home system property using SpEL too.

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['java.home']}")
private String javaHome;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` which used `Dotenv` to load the properties and then wrap that in a `PropertySource`. That way you will be able to use regular Spring mechanism to replace the values.

```java
public DotenvEnvironmentProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

@Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, 
      SpringApplication application) {

      Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.load();
      Properties envProps = new Properties();
      for (DotenvEntry entry : dotenv.entries()) {
        envProps.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
      }
      environment.getPropertySources()
          .addAfter(SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME, new PropertiesPropertySource("dotenv", envProps);
    }
}
```

This will register the `Dotenv` loaded properties into the `Environment` used by Spring to replace the values.

**NOTE:** You could also write a dedicated `PropertySource` implementation that wraps the `Dotenv` and use that instead. You can do this by extending the `EnumerablePropertySource` and implement it.

Now you can reference the properties as you usually would do with Spring.

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "some_topic", groupId = "${SOME_KAFKA_GROUPID}", containerFactory = "some_container_name")
```

This should probably also simplify other code you are using which references `Dotenv` as you can remove it and use normal Spring mechanisms (and you could even move the properties to your `application.properties` or yaml or in profile specific ones).